# Fake bold applied inconsistently to section titles

Tags: section-titles

From a few answers here I borrowed the method of applying fake bold in order to overcome the lack of bold characters in Gentium font in Russian encoding.

Unfortunately that has a weird side effect. The very first section in every chapter may appear not bold at all depending on the layout of the previous text. If one would un-comment the only commented out word in the MWE below, then the first section title would be bold all right. Only those sections whose title is balancing perfectly on the edge of the next page have this problem, but it is not really the top of the page which causes it. It has to be a very specific amount of text on the previous page.

What is this solution lacking for consistent boldness of the section titles?

```
\documentclass[12pt,smallroyalvopaper]{memoir}
\usepackage{gentium}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=russian]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=0.75in, right=0.875in, top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage{xfakebold}
\newcommand{\tfbseries}{\setBold\aftergroup\unsetBold\aftergroup\ignorespaces}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setBoldness}[1]{\def\fake@bold{#1}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\tfbseries}{}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\HUGE\tfbseries}{\chaptertitlename{ }\thechapter}{20pt}{\HUGE}

%\makenomenclature
\begin{document}

\chapter{Глава}
\label{chap:Confrontation}

глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава 

глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава

глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава %глава

\section{Секция один}
\label{sect:TheFind}

глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава 

\section{Секция два}
\label{sect:TheFindTwo}

глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `xfakebold` code is quite simple minded: it simply inserts a `\pdfliteral`.
*[Update 2023: this is no longer always true, xfakebold now uses internally the pdfrender package and works across pagebreaks with pdflatex and lualatex (but not with xelatex).]* Such a literal looses its effect at page breaks. Due to the asynchronic page breaking of TeX your section  command is executed while page 1 is build and the pdfliteral is there. Then the section moves to page 2.

A much better alternative (with pdflatex, for luatex and xelatex embolden the font is better) is the `pdfrender` package which uses a colorstack to save the state and reinstate it on the next page. Compare e.g. this (and look also at the footer):

```
\documentclass[12pt,smallroyalvopaper]{memoir}
\usepackage{xfakebold}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\usepackage{lipsum}
 \pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\setBold
\lipsum[1-4]
\unsetBold
some text

\newpage
\begingroup
\pdfrender{TextRenderingMode=2,LineWidth=0.4}
\lipsum[1-4]
\endgroup
some text
\end{document}
```

For your example this means:

```
\documentclass[12pt,smallroyalvopaper]{memoir}
\usepackage{gentium}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=russian]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=0.75in, right=0.875in, top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\newcommand\tfbseries{\pdfrender{TextRenderingMode=2,LineWidth=0.4}}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large \tfbseries}{}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\HUGE\tfbseries}{\chaptertitlename{ }\thechapter}{20pt}{\HUGE}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Глава}
\label{chap:Confrontation}

глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава

глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава

глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава %глава

\section{Секция один}
\label{sect:TheFind}

глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава

\section{Секция два}
\label{sect:TheFindTwo}

глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава глава

\end{document}
```

[image]