# How to add (fake) bold feature to fallback font using luaotfload luatex

Tags: fonts, luatex, bold, cjk, luaotfload

I have this in my preamble:

```latex
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
luaotfload.add_fallback("FallbackFonts", {
  "Noto Color Emoji:mode=harf",
  "Noto Sans CJK JP:"
})
\end{luacode*}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}[RawFeature={fallback=FallbackFonts}]
```

But I don't understand how to add bold feature to fallback fonts, well, at least to `Noto Sans CJK JP`. I can, for example, do this:

```latex
\newfontfamily{\jserif}{Noto Serif CJK JP}
\fontspec[AutoFakeBold=1.5]{Noto Serif CJK JP}
```

Which will add ability to make `Noto Serif CJK JP` font bold when in `\textbf{}` command. But this is only for one specific font which is used directly, not as a fallback font.

So, my question is, how can I add bold feature to fallback font `Noto Sans CJK JP`?

Update: The bold font must be applied in the same situations as any other regular font which support bold feature out of the box, e.g., when using `\textbf{}`.

Comment: This https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520874/fake-bold-applied-inconsistently-to-section-titles may be useful

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
luaotfload.add_fallback("FallbackFonts", {
  "Noto Color Emoji:mode=harf;",
  "Noto Sans CJK JP:embolden=10;"
})
\end{luacode*}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}[RawFeature={fallback=FallbackFonts}]
\begin{document}
 的 
blub
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I already tried it — it's always bold. I need it to be bold only when the macros say so (`\textbf`, `\bfseries`) (conditional).

Comment: well as you didn't provide a sensible example I guessed. Ask a new, better question.

Comment: I only can emphasize that bold should be as a regular bold — when used with appropriate macros. I can't give an example, because I need to know the answer to my question in order to provide one.